# How secure LocalStorage on a SPA

Tags: security, front-end, code-security

I'm developing an Ionic 4 based (Angular) web application. It has a lot of logic on it and needs to store session specific data (such as a JWT, selected language, among other preferences and temporary settings).

But recently I've been working a lot on its security. The last piece I'm trying to sort out is removing everything from the localStorage (specially user info and the JWT). I have contemplated cyphering the info using crypto-js (with AES256), but anyway the key will be on the client at some point. Also I contemplated obfuscating the data using atob() btoa() methods but that's even easier to sort out.

The things I'm exploring right now are:

- Having everything on a document based database such as DynamoDB, but
  in that way all user's data will be there anyway, in case everything
  access it
- Using a singleton that holds all that data, with the
  disadvantage that it won't be persistent

What would you recommend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your threat model? That is, which scenarios are you trying to defend against?

Comment: User info an JWT tokens are related to the user, why would you try to encrypt it on the client side? as you already mentions, they client needs the key anyway.